# Trigger an action based on Prometheus metrics

Tags: prometheus

I need to trigger a bash command based on Prometheus metrics (not alerts). I found https://home.robusta.dev/ that can execute an action, but it consumes only Prometheus alerts. Please recommend a tool that fits my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus has an [API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/), you can get metrics with just anything capable of performing HTTP requests:

```sh
curl 'http://prometheus.example.com:9090/api/v1/query?query=up!=1'
```

On success you get a JSON like this:

```json
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "up",
          "instance": "foo",
          "job": "test"
        },
        "value": [
          1646896269.124,
          "0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "up",
          "instance": "bar",
          "job": "test"
        },
        "value": [
          1646896269.124,
          "0"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you can add some logic: parse the response, make another query, run a script, etc.